# Python list appending issue

Tags: python, list, append

I ran into a rather weird problem with python list appending today. I was trying to create an array whose each element would be like a C `struct`. One of these elements was a list by itself. This is the problematic code:

```
class players:
    name='placeholder'
    squad=list()

teams=list()
teams.append(players())
teams.append(players())
teams[0].name="abc"
teams[1].name="xyz"
teams[0].squad.append("Joe")

for w in teams:
    print(w.name)
    print(w.squad)
```

The output I expected is:

```
abc
['Joe']
xyz
[]
```

Since I only added a member to `squad` for teams[0]. But the output I get is:

```
abc
['Joe']
xyz
['Joe']
```

The name is set fine but the `.append` appended it to both elements of `teams`!

What causes this and how can I work around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that in your class definition, `squad` and `name` are class variables, not instance variables. When a new `player` object is initialized, it is essentially sharing the same `squad` variable across all instances of the player. Instead, you want to define an `__init__` method for the `player` class that explicitly separates the instance-specific variables.

```
class players:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'placeholder'
        self.squad = []
```

Then, when you initialize your new `player` object, it has its own `squad` variable. The rest of your code should work just fine now, with only the correct object's `squad` being appended to.

Comment: And some people say JavaScript is weird